# Not getting any information from Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'm implementing Facebook login on my website, it's working without error but ultimately I'm not able to get any information of a user.
I've following code.

```
<?php
include 'library.php';
include 'facebook.php';

$app_id     = "XXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXX";
$site_url   = "XXXXXXXXX";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'     => $app_id,
'secret'    => $app_secret,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
try{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    $user = NULL;
}
}
if($user){
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope'         => 'email',
    'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
    ));
}
if($user){
Echo "Email : " . $user_profile['email'];
}
    $user_fbid  = $fbuser;
    $user_email = $user_profile["email"];
    $user_fname = $user_profile["first_name"];
    $user_image = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_fbid."/picture?type=large";
    echo $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array('scope' => 'email,read_stream'));
```

What's wrong with this? Can anyone point out? I've gone though a number of questions but none of them seemed to work for me & I finally ended up posting a question myself.

**EDIT**
When asking for login, it displays permissions correctly like email, friend list, your likes etc. So basically it's asking correctly & even though I approve, information is not coming up. Tried with a couple of users.

Comment: Is an exception thrown? Try to display `$e->getMessage()` if so..

Comment: No exception thrown, not with getMessage() as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try use this code, and work from there ... That's how I figured it out

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?php

require_once("fb/facebook.php");
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'XXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'fileUpload' => false, // optional
    'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$loginParams = array('scope' => 'email');
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($loginParams);


$logoutParams = array('next' => 'http://fb_logouturi');
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($logoutParams);

echo $uid . '</br>';

echo 'Login:<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">' . $loginUrl . '</a></br>';
echo 'Logout:<a href="' . $logoutUrl . '">' . $logoutUrl . '</a></br>';

if($uid) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "</br>First Name: " . $user_profile['first_name'];
        echo "</br>Last Name: " . $user_profile['last_name'];
        echo "</br>Email: " . $user_profile['email'];
        echo "</br>Gender: " . $user_profile['gender'];
        echo "</br><img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $uid ."/picture?type=large'>";

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }


?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, your code is exactly what I posted in my question. Is this the answer?

Comment: And yes if(!$user) doesn't work as well, if you meant the same

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was just quoting your code there ... I'll take a look at my code, and get back to you ... Just a little drunk right now

Comment: I'm trying to implement this so what I'm gonna do is put login button in login screen & upon successful login user will be redirected to index page. And well your code is working fine, cheers :)

Comment: One more thing, can you help me suggesting some ways so that user can keep logged in to my website for about 15-30 days without being logged out?

Comment: Use cookies :D ... Basically what I do, is use the users facebook info to register the user (Storing the information in my database) and then create a cookie

Comment: Yead I figured it out that too, thanks for the help bdw! Cheers :D

Comment: Hey can you help pointing the correct cookie to store? There seems to be a lot more sessions running & I'm not able to find the correct one.